# Don't understand glutPostRedisplay and glIdleFunc

Tags: opengl

I don't quite understand what the `glutPostRedisplay()` is used. It seems like when I call that in my function, at next frame `display()` function will be called. However I don't know how does that function relate to animation. We often register a function for physical computation as `Idle` function and do some computation there. However, if we change the parameters, like rotation, position of the objects that have animation, even if we don't call that `glutPostRedisplay()`, the `display()` function itself will redraw the scene. Why do we need to call `glutPostRedisplay()`?

The second question is about `glutIdleFunc()`. My question is: is that possible the CPU is so busy that we don't have idle time at each frame?

Comment: Do you have any sample code to help us understand your situation?

Answer (score 3):

Here's some pseudocode illustrating the GLUT main loop

```
redisplay = True

glutMainLoop:

    ...

    forever:
        switch(eventsPoll):
            case KEYBOARD:
                if(eventKey):
                    call_keyboardFunction
            case MOUSE:
                if(eventMouseMove):
                    if(mousebutton_pressed):
                        call_mouseMotionFunc
                    else:
                        call_passiveMotionFunc
                if(eventMouseButton):
                    call_mouseFunc
            case ... // other input events

        if( redisplay ):
            call_displayFunc
            redisplay = False
        else
            call_idleFunc


glutPostRedisplay:
    redisplay = True
```

The purpose of glutPostRedisplay is to set the flag that indicates to the glutMainLoop, that in its next iteration it shall call the display function.

Comment: So, IdleFunc is like when you don't call redisplay, it will call idle?Then when will display be called? I know when you resize the window, it will call display function. What are other situations?

Comment: @YanLi: the display func is called either if an update is explicitly requested (glutPostRedisplay) or if the window's contents have been invalidated (damaged) and require a redraw. The OS will send such an event whenever parts of a window got visible that were not before. Increasing the size of a window makes new pixels visible, hence the redraw; however reducing a window's size does not mandate this.

Comment: Then how about idle function, when will it be called?

Comment: @YanLi: It gets called when there are no more events in the event queue. It get's called when there's nothing to do and the program is idle. Once the idle function returns the event queue is checked again, and if there's still nothing there, idle gets called again.

Comment: is that possible that CPU is too busy, and no idle time is left?

Comment: @YanLi: Calling or not the idle function is not based on CPU time left, but on the presence of any events to be processed by the application. As soon as there are no events for your programm to processed the idle handler will be called.